# Selection checkbox with triggers?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have this control (see picture). I like when check one option in this control,  using styles or with triggers other option enable or disable. This is valid or I have other option for do that?
[alt text http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/5819/combos.jpg](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/5819/combos.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your XAML, but you could bind each `CheckBox`'s `IsChecked` property to the same thing:

```
<CheckBox.IsChecked>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
        <Binding Path="."/>
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="..."/>
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.IsChecked>
```

The converter (`IMultiValueConverter`) would then determine whether the first value matches the selected value, and return true/false accordingly.